# How can I include new values in the date range list associated with the date fields type in the OroCRM dashboard widget?

Tags: orocrm

I need to include a new value in the list of date ranges for a custom widget. The new value will be "Yesterday", it will appear with today, this week, this month, etc. for date type fields.

If anyone knows OroCRM and knows how to do it please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the Oro\Bundle\DashboardBundle\Provider\Converters\FilterDateRangeConverter, and most likely you have to override the $valueTypes property of \Oro\Bundle\FilterBundle\Form\Type\Filter\DateRangeFilterType form type.